# How to convert UTF uppercase characters to lowercase in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I want to convert uppercase strings to lowercase strings.

for examples, the string `'LÄCHERLICH'` is converted to `'lÄcherlich'` by using the method

```
 str.lower()
```

Answer (score 3):

Which Python version is it? In Python 3, using `lower()` converts it properly:

```
>>> x = 'LÄCHERLICH'
>>> print(x.lower())
lächerlich
```

With Python 2, you should use unicode strings (and don't forget to define coding in the very beginning of your file):

```
# coding: utf-8
x = u'LÄCHERLICH'
print x.lower().encode('utf8')
```

Comment: I am using version 2.7

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = 'LÄCHERLICH'
print a.decode('utf8').lower()
```

`decode` will work as if you want to use `lower()` on `u'LÄCHERLICH'`.

Answer (score 0):

**For Python 2.7**

The problem is that when you're declaring the string it's taking as ascii you have to define it's in UTF at the time of declaration or afterwards.

```
In [17]: str = 'LÄCHERLICH' # didn't specify  encoding(so ASCII by default)

In [18]: print str.lower()
lÄcherlich

In [19]: str = u'LÄCHERLICH'  #declaring that it's UTF

In [20]: print str.lower()
lächerlich
```

Converting it after declaration :

```
In [21]: str = 'LÄCHERLICH' 

In [22]: print str.decode('utf8').lower()
lächerlich
```